# jquery dynamic ID assignment won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that its values should appear in a template before submitting 
I have tried everything in a small file for testing, works fine.

but in the project, it won't.
The code below shows that the first line won't work 
the second line works fine

```
$(".contractform").on("blur", "input", function() {

  $("input").map(function() {

    // this line does not work 
    $('#main_doc div #' + this.id).html(this.val());

    // this line works fine 
    $("#main_doc div  #ref_no").html("10a");
  });
});
```

the error that i have in console is that

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #main_doc div #
>   jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:13136

I have checked several questions around here about assigning dynamic ID but it won't work in my situation, works only in a test experimental files.

Comment: Show your html as well

Comment: @TemaniAfif How is this going to fix the error?

Comment: html is very large

Comment: @MohammedOmer Show just html code for your `<input>` tags

Comment: console.log('#main_doc div #'+this.id); outbuts the correct ID but the jquery file throw an error id i use the above syntax

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: i have add paer of HTML code

Comment: yes it does not make sense , it blows my mind